# Cloth simulation moves mesh away

Tags: cloth-simulation

I cannot find any information on this issue, but it's simple. I have a mesh, I add a Cloth simulation modifier to it, and it moves the mesh below the grid.

Why is it doing this annoying behaviour? The transforms are applied and mesh has no tris, no double vertices, nothing!

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Are you one Frame 1 of the Timeline? If you are on a later Frame, the mesh will move to the position offset for the selected frame.

Comment: Oh man. Now I feel dumb. I had hid the timeline and it was on a random frame. Ridiculous.
Write an actual wanswer to this, to I can upvote it and accept it for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the timeline isn't on Frame 1, the simulation will move the mesh to where it would be after that many frames.

Move the frame selector back to the first frame and it will work as you expect.